# It is not giving userid in url when i visit this route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, url-parameters

```
router.get("/dashboard/profile/:userid", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const userid = req.params.user.id;
    // request.user is getting fetched from Middleware after token authentication
      const user = await User.findById(userid);
      res.json(user);
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ message: "Error in Fetching user" });
  }
});

module.exports = router
```

this is my get route i tried to get params.id from user but it is not working

Comment: Typo, `req.params.user.id;` vs `req.params.userid;`, to match path pattern, voting to close.

Comment: if you console.log("somthing") in the route ("/dashboard/profile/:userid"), can you see the somthing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this

```
const userid = req.params.user.id
```

with

```
const userid = req.params.userid
```

Comment: http://localhost:3000/dashboard/profile only getting this in url

Comment: you have to send userid at the end of the url

Answer (score 0):

`userid` is a single key. But you separated with `user.id` . so use

```
const userid = req.params.userid;
```

instead of

```
const userid = req.params.user.id;
```

> its not working only getting localhost:3000/dashboard/profile ?

You are missing the `userid` value on your path.

Please check it there is three segment.

```
dashboard/profile/:userid
 1         2         3
```

But your path are (***problem***)

```
localhost:3000/dashboard/profile
                 1         2
```

please don't consider the host name and port. calculate after `/`

**solution**

```
localhost:3000/dashboard/profile/YourUserID
                1         2        3(//add your userid here)
```

Comment: its not working only getting http://localhost:3000/dashboard/profile this

Comment: yes you are missing the userid value on your path. That path look like `localhost:3000/dashboard/profile/87686youruserid` . Please check it there three segment but your path are 2. please don't consider the host name and port. calculate after `/`

Comment: so what i should do to fix it

Comment: @PratikZinjurde check my latest updated answer

Comment: im using react so should i also change react path <Link to="/dashboard/profile">Profile</Link> to <Link to="/dashboard/profile/:userid">Profile</Link>

Comment: yes but userid is dynamic. so pass the exact value like something `123 or id string` instead of `:userid`